# Unexplained behavior of round() with Decimal type

Tags: python

Using Python 3.9.9:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, Context, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> round( Decimal( '4.605', context=Context( rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP ) ), 2 )
Decimal('4.60')
```

With ROUND_HALF_UP, shouldn't the above result be 4.61?

Am I misusing or misunderstanding [the documentation for ROUND_HALF_UP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) or [the documentation for constructing a Decimal with Context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal)?

Comment: From your second link: “The purpose of the context argument is determining what to do if value is a malformed string.“ This suggests that to do anything else with a context, it must be set as the local context.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thanks!

And indeed, ```setcontext( Context( rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP ) )``` results in the correct rounding.